# Is $e^{-x}$ equal to $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \Bigg(1-\dfrac{x}{n}\Bigg)^n$?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, exponential-function

I just want the confirmation, is it apposite to think that

$$e^{x} = \lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \Bigg(1+\dfrac{x}{n}\Bigg)^n$$

Replacing $x$ with $-x$, we get the relation in the title.

Comment: Yes, you are right. You can place any real $x$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, You can change the sign but I would like to answer why the changing the sign will be OK

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1-\frac x{n}\right)^n$$

- **Case $1$**

Using [L'Hôpital's rule for type $1^{\infty}$](https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/%7Ekouba/CalcOneDIRECTORY/lhopitaldirectory/LHopital.html)

$1^{\infty}$LH-Rule:

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}f^g = \text{exp}{\left(\lim_{n\to\infty}(f(n)-1)g(n)\right)}$$

$e^{(1-\frac x{n}-1)\times n} = e^{-x}$

- **Case $2$**
  [Using Binomial Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem)

$$\begin{align*}
\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1-\frac x{n}\right)^n
& = \lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1-\frac x{1!} +\frac{x^2}{2!} - \frac {x^3}{3!}+...\right)\\
& = e^{-x}\\
\end{align*}$$

Answer (score 2):

To prove your statement simply substitute $y=-x$ finding

$$\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}\left( 1+\frac{y}{n}  \right)^n=e^y=e^{-x}$$